# How to prove? $|\sin(nx)| \lt n|\sin(x)|$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know how to prove this?

For  $n= 2,3,4,\ldots$ and  $ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2} $,
$$|\sin(nx)| \lt n|\sin(x)|  $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Why don't you start with the first few $N$ and analyse what happens there... also post your results then!

Comment: In fact the inequality is valid for all $x\ne \pi k$ (in the exceptional points it turns out to be equality).

Comment: @user What do you mean by $x\ne \pi k$? It is given that $0<x<\pi/2$.

Comment: @A.Γ I mean that the inequality is valid for all $-\infty<x<\infty$ except for the points $x=\pi k$. In other words the restriction $0<x<\pi/2$ plays no role.

Comment: @user How come?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I tried but can't call it a proof.

Comment: 〖|sin〗⁡2x |(=|2 sin⁡x  cos⁡x |≤2)|  sin⁡x |

Comment: @mahyarp See for example the proof of Lord below.

Comment: @user can't get how his proof leads to the answer

Comment: @mahyarp It remains only to take absolute value of both sides and use $\left|\sum x_i\right|\le \sum |x_i|$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\sin Nx}{\sin x}=\frac{e^{Nix}-e^{-Nix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}
=e^{-(N-1)ix}\frac{e^{2iNx}-1}{e^{2ix}-1}
=e^{-(N-1)ix}(1+e^{2ix}+\cdots+e^{2(N-1)ix})$$
etc.

Comment: you want to say it's less than 'n'?